# ngbtoolTip inside ag-grid does not close onscroll

Tags: tooltip, angular8, ag-grid, ng-bootstrap, ag-grid-angular

I have commercial ag-grid withing angular 8.0
applying ngb-tooltip on one of the cells
Onscroll tooltip not closing when reach the border of the grid. And goes over it to the header of the page

1. I tried to get tooltip as a  `@ViewChild('tooltip', { static: true }) public tooltip: NgbTooltip;`
   in the "cell element"(child of ag-grid)
   and closed when scroll is fired by using addEventListener on the grid
   but cannot catch scroll event, I'm able to get "click, mouseover events and so on
   bot not "scroll"
2. I tried to use addEventListener for scroll at the parent element ag-drid itself but also
   cannot catch only scroll event

I know that inside ag-grid DOM is messed-up nd cannot find any solution
ngbtooltip triggers="manual" and open on click and closing on click inside